# Microsoft Integration Runtime Configuration Manager Failed to connect to the database. Error message: Bad JSON escape sequence:

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have successfully configured `Self-Hosted Integration Runtime` in `Azure Data Factory` on `Azure Portal` as well as `Self-Hosted IR Node` on my local machine and `linked service` connects successfully to my local `sql server` from `Azure Portal`
[image]

but when I test connection  within IR connection manager on my local machine to connect to local `sql server`  it gives me this error

[image]

can anyone help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is Server name with single back slash. I copied Server name from ssms which uses

```
R\SQLEXPRESS
```

but then i checked the connection string that Self-Hosted on Azure is using to connect to `on premise SQL Server` it uses double back slashes

```
R\\SQLEXPRESS
```

and after changing to double back slash it works 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could refer to my working steps as below.

1.Follow this [guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/create-self-hosted-integration-runtime) Create Self IR on the portal.

[image]

2.Get the Auth Key to start the ADF IR local management.

[image]

3.Fill the sql server name and database name in the Diagnostics Tag.

[image]

Comment: I have followed all the above mentioned steps still doesn't work